# jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway cursor - constructor argument

Tags: spring-integration

I am using jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway to fetch the result from stored procedure. I have a cursor return type which is working fine with static constructor argument.

```
<int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="O_TEST_RC" type="#{T(oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes).CURSOR}" direction="OUT"  return-type="testCursor"/>

<bean id="testCursor" class="package.TestCursor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>2015/10/14</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

How can make this constructor argument dynamic with payload. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `CURSOR` you should use `<int-jdbc:returning-resultset>` and provide some `RawMapper` to build the target domain object already and avoid such a low-level API like extension of Oracle -specific `Cursor` type.

Comment: Testcursor class that implements SqlReturnType for customizable data handling and it require contractor parameter to handle business logic..is there a way to pass the argument dynamically in SI. Suggestion please.

Comment: No-op. You have to re-write logic to accept that argument in the `getTypeValue()` implementation. The `return-type` requires a reference for the `singleton`  bean. So, you can specify its properties only once at initialization phase. If you would like to get access to the `payoad` of a `requestMessage`, you should consider to use something like `ThreadLocal` before `<jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>` to store and clear it somehow afterwards. Otherwise it would be better to distinguish the logic and let procedure adapter perform DB logic and everything rest move into the `<enricher>`

Comment: Threadlocal will be the best suite..Thanks for your suggestion.